# Google App Engine CNAME record for customers

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, googledns

I have an app engine instance running with `*.mydomain.com` as whitelisted domain. 
Each user of my site has a subdomain e.g. `foo.mydomain.com` or `bar.mydomain.com`. (I have done this by pointing a `CNAME` record to `ghs.googlehosted.com.`

I want my users to be able to host my page on their domains e.g. `hello.foo.com` pointing to `foo.mydomain.com`.

Is this possible with GAE due to the whitelist domains and if not is this possible in google-cloud in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so unfortunately in order to achieve this I could not use AppEngine. Instead I created the same deployment in ContainerEngine and exposed a static IP to which i create A records `foo.mydomain.com A 104.X.Y.Z` and now clients can create `CNAME` records to `foo.mydomain.com`.

Hope this helps someone in the future